# How to load a snapshot in Jazz source control?

Tags: build, load, snapshot, jazz

So Jazz source control lets you snapshot a repository workspace.

But how would I load a particular snapshot of a workspace on the command line? Doesn't seem like a lot of point to a snapshot if I can't load the project as it was at that point in time...?

ed... I have found a 'new... repository workspace from snapshot' in the RAD plugin... now to find how to do the same on the command line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Take a look at `scm help create workspace`. You should see a `--snapshot` argument that will create a new workspace from the given snapshot.

2) See `scm help load`.

Answer (score 1):

A snapshot is just a list of version identifiers.  A repository workspace is what contains the content.

So you are actually asking two questions, which may help to clarify your search.

1) How do I create a new repository workspace from a snapshot via the command line

and

2) How do I load an existing repository workspace to my local filesystem via the command line

I would suggest asking your question on the http://jazz.net forums in the Rational Team Concert section.  The development team is very responsive in answering questions and will be able to give you an answer that is accurate for the build that you are running.